# Possible to stop the current execution of commands in command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there any command to stop the execution of current running commands in windows `cmd` prompt?

Comment: Do you mean something like `kill` command in Linux?

Answer (score 40):

Did you try the following key combination: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

**UPDATE**

For Windows 10 (cmd, PowerShell) you can use one of this:

- <kbd>Right CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Pause/Break</kbd>

Comment: If you are running a Python script, CTRL + Pause/Break won't be caught by the Python program and will actually stop it.

Comment: and what is the batch command to exit a cmd from another cmd?

Comment: These controls no longer work in OS10 v1909 b18363.592. Another superuser suggests running CMD with admin privileges and checking that "defaults" doesn't intercept ctrl commands, none of which make a difference. Has Microsoft changed the keys yet again?

Answer (score 5):

First use `tasklist` to show all running tasks. Then use `taskkill /PID 1234` to kill a specific task (PID is the second column) or use `taskkill /IM program.exe` to kill a specific programm (all instances).

Or just use <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to kill current running programm in current cmd window.

Answer (score 5):

The best way:

**`CTRL + Break(pause)`**

Comment: Cool! I have tried  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> several time on windows 10 console and it was still holding. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break(Pause)</kbd> really works!

Comment: @Cherry, I had same problem. But with `right Ctrl` it works as expected.